# How and by which way I can measure my speed when I move .( the phone moves)

Tags: android

I need a code to measure the distance from point to point when i move the phone 
really its bothering me and make me so tired to find this code .
any help ??

Comment: What do you want "measure my speed when I move" or "measure the distance from point to point" ?

Comment: when i move ,, obviously i start from point to end up to another point

Answer (score 1):

1. By using the [Location.getSpeed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()) method or
2. [by dividing the distance between the two points by the amount of time it took to cover that distance](http://physics.tutorvista.com/motion/speed.html)

Comment: my main project to find the distance by :
speed*time
because that i need the speed without connected it with my location or any thing like google map way